# Crystal Reports Pie Chart Display Budget Unspent and Expenses

Tags: crystal-reports, pie-chart

I'm trying to create a pie chart that will show the total budget and what has been spent and not spent. Here is a sample data case:

Group 1 Header: Company
    Company 1: Total Budget: 60,000

Group 2 Header: Project 
    Project A

Detail: Expenses

```
Project A Supplies: 10,000
Project A Wages:     5,000
```

Group 2 Footer: Project

```
Project A Total Expenses: 15,000
```

Group 2 Header: Project B

Detail:Expenses

```
Project B Supplies: 18,000
Project B Wages:     7,000
```

Group 2 Footer: Project

```
Project B Total Expenses: 25,000
```

Group 1 Footer: Company

```
Company 1: Unspent Budget: 60,000 - 15,000 - 25,000 = 20,000
```

Here is what the Pie Chart should look like:

```
Project A 15,000
       |
     * *
   *     *
  * *   * * 
 *   * *   * -- Project B 25,000
 *    *    *
  *    *  *
   *     *
   | * *        
Unspent Budget 20,000
```

I've tried a variety of solutions but to no avail. I tried creating a dummy detail record with the budget amount, and then used the 3 formula method for creating a running total of the expenses.  I then created a formula called @PieChartAmount that goes something like this:

If ProjectName = "Budget" Then {BudgetAmount} - {@TotalExpenses} Else {ExpenseAmount}

When I run the report and display the @PieChartAmount it shows as follows:

Project A Supplies:         10,000
Project A Wages:             5,000
Project B Supplies:         18,000
Project B Wages:             7,000
Project C Budget Remaining:     20,000

These amounts are all correct, but when the Pie Chart renders, the unspent budget amount shows as 60,000 instead of 20,000 as follows:

```
Project A 15,000
       |
     * *
   *     *
  * *   * * 
 *   * *   * -- Project B 25,000
 *    *    *
  *    *  *
   *     *
   | * *        
Unspent Budget 60,000
```

It's as if the @TotalExpenses is not calculated when the Pie Chart is rendered. Open to trying something different if you have a good idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By changing the formula to calculate at the group level, everything worked out okay.

If {@ProjectName} = "Budget Unspent" Then {@Budget} - Sum({@Expenses},{Project.CompanyID}) Else Sum({@Expenses},{@ProjectName})